# Will an iOS app that is new on a specific market be listed on the Release Date list on the App Store?

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I have an iOS app which includes some specific national contents. For that reason, I have so far only made it available for one single national market.
Now I am adding contents for some more countries, so I will release an update which will be available on these markets too.
Then, the app could be regarded as "new" on these additional markets.

My question is if this will be reflected on the App Store: Will the app be listed on the Release Date lists for the markets where it had not been available before?
Has anyone got some experience of similar situations?

Answer (score 0):

No it won't. It only appears as new the first time the bundle id is accepted within iTunes Connect. The actual App Stores don't matter in the 'new' designation.